# "styles":[...] in angular.json not working

Tags: json, sass, angular-material

I have been trying to implement Angular Material in my project and I imported a prebuilt theme in `styles.scss`. But that didn't work. So I tried to add it to `angular.json` file but seems that that didn't work out either. Then I finally figured out that whatever added in the `"styles":[]` in `angular.json` didn't work in my project(even `styles.scss` is not working). Does anyone know what might be the issue?

My `angular.json` file

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "unified-product-assessment": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/unified-product-assessment",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets/"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input":"node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
            "commonChunk": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "7kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.prod.config.js"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "unified-product-assessment:build:production",
              "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.prod.config.js"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "unified-product-assessment:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "port": 5000,
            "publicHost": "http://localhost:5000",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "unified-product-assessment:build",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "85c84fd2-00e2-4930-b2a7-4da897f60d34",
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
         ],
```

Also do not forget to restart the application with *ng serve* for changes to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem I was facing was since I was using Microfrontends to implement my application I had to add the .scss file in the angular.json file of the shell.